# Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1 in flutter

Tags: flutter

After I run my flutter project in my android device, I found this in my console. How to solve this.Please help me.

```
Launching lib\main.dart on CRO U00 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
F:\FlutterProjects\airdropbazar\android\app\src\debug\AndroidManifest.xml Error:
    uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 16 cannot be smaller than version 17 declared in library [:flutter_inappwebview] F:\FlutterProjects\airdropbazar\build\flutter_inappwebview\intermediates\library_manifest\debug\AndroidManifest.xml as the library might be using APIs not available in 16
    Suggestion: use a compatible library with a minSdk of at most 16,
        or increase this project's minSdk version to at least 17,
        or use tools:overrideLibrary="com.pichillilorenzo.flutter_inappwebview" to force usage (may lead to runtime failures)

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 16 cannot be smaller than version 17 declared in library [:flutter_inappwebview] F:\FlutterProjects\airdropbazar\build\flutter_inappwebview\intermediates\library_manifest\debug\AndroidManifest.xml as the library might be using APIs not available in 16
    Suggestion: use a compatible library with a minSdk of at most 16,
        or increase this project's minSdk version to at least 17,
        or use tools:overrideLibrary="com.pichillilorenzo.flutter_inappwebview" to force usage (may lead to runtime failures)

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 10s
Finished with error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The flutter_inappwebview plugin only supports Android: minSdkVersion 17 and higher. Please check the requirements here: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_inappwebview.

Go to your apps build.gradle file, under Android, and in  defaultConfig {}, change your minSdkVersion to 17.